# Make an html/java code on wix dissapear once clicked

Tags: javascript, html, click

I'm running into an issue, and I hope you can help me. ^^
First hello everyone! It's my first post so I'll try to make it as clean as possible^^.

I want to make an html/java code window to disappear once it's clicked , so the content behind it becomes accessible while the person still gets redirected to where they're suppose to (on a second page).

If that's not possible or too complicated, the other solution would be to open another window simultaneously, either replacing the original one, or opening a new page (a duplicate of the first page without html code).

Any idea how I could manage that? Knowing that I have no knowledge in code whatsoever. *_*'     Also i should add that this is dedicated to mobile only, not that it would change a lot of things.

I have to add that my website is build on wix.
If anyone has an idea, or need more info, let me know.

here is part of the code:

```
<div id="app"> </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){
            var App = {
              android_id: '',
              ios_id: '',
              cat: '',
              pbk: '',
              cnt:'5',
              mute: '',
              creative:'managed',
              subid:'',          
              pview:'',
              display_mode:'min',
              video_length:'',
              parent_url:window.location.origin.toString()
            };
            var block = document.querySelector('#app')
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.style.width='100%';
            iframe.style.border=0;
            var src = 'https://example.net/widget/Index.html?v=2';

            for (var param in  App) src+='&'+param+'='+App[param];
            iframe.src=src;
            block.appendChild(iframe);
            window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
                var origin = event.origin || event.originalEvent.origin;
                if (origin!=="https://example.net")return;
                iframe.style.height=event.data+'px';
                if(event.data=='noAds')block.removeChild(iframe);
            }, false);
        })();
    </script>
```

By the way, this html/java wix code window covers a contact box.
Hope you can help me.
Best,

Lily

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

`document.getElementById("app").addEventListener('click', false, function(){
  this.hidden=true;
})`

You can insert that into the javascript and it will make the app div disappear when you click on it. The other things you suggested aren't hard, if you make a more firm decision it would be easy to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you know at which place should I applied the code? I replaced the "app" by the actual app id, but it doesn't seem to work. I think it might be safer to go with option 2 since it will open a new window, there is less chance of something going wrong for the people clicking. And thanks for your first answer! :) Also i should add that this is dedicated to mobile only, not that it would change a lot of things.

Comment: You can add the following code at the bottom of the file after the closing script tag ('</script>').

`<script>
document.getElementById("app").addEventListener('click', false, function(){
  this.hidden=true;
})
</script>
`